# Generate XSD from my model

Tags: wcf, rest, xsd

I am writing a WCF REST service, and I am needing to generate my XSD's which provide the information for my models.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

It would be nice to have it generate the validation within the XSD too, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe
```